# Page on github wont publish (error 404 not found)

Tags: github, sass, publishing, repo

My page wont go live when i try to publish it on github: https://starzje.github.io/NFT-card/

in "pages build and deployment", im both getting errors on deploy and built parts on github.

My file is just normal index.html and style.css, nothing else in it (just a folder with few imgs).

I did install sass and used bootstrap on a project before this (but there is no scss in this project).

github errors:

````
**DEPLOY ERROR**
Error: Error: No uploaded artifact was found! Please check if there are any errors at build step.
Error: Error: No uploaded artifact was found! Please check if there are any errors at build step.```


**BUILD ERROR:**

Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error while converting 'assets/css/style.scss':
                    No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - /github/workspace/docs
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [mentioned in 2019](https://github.blog/2009-12-29-bypassing-jekyll-on-github-pages/#:%7E:text=It%20is%20now%20possible%20to,and%20pushing%20it%20to%20GitHub.), try and add a `.nojekyll` file at the root of your [`NFT-card` repository](https://github.com/starzje/NFT-card).

That should allow you to bypass Jekyll completely: it would not try to apply a [`jekyll/minima`](https://github.com/jekyll/minima) theme at all.

Comment: It works now. Does it mean i will have to include .nojeky11 in every repo from now on?

Comment: @Sta yes, for those which do not need Jekyll.